# Div not centered from ie8 to ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, modal-dialog

An important div in my website has moved from center of the screen to right-bottom when i moved from ie8 to ie11, i tried different things but i couldn't fix it :

```
.ModalDialog{
    border:1px solid #3C4749;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    min-height:1px;
    top:250px;
    left:450px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

How can i have a perfectly centered div horizontally and vertically for ie11 for any screen resolution (or most of them) ?

Comment: you have used left and top position, how could be this is center?

Comment: It is an existing application, i'm a newbie in css. But i can assure you that it   is centered for ie8. (maybe just for my screen then)

Comment: Position relative is not necessary and is even counter-productive. You should use a fake table layout (DO NOT USE REAL TABLES). Check this: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: @user3557384 maybe that was centered for some specific screen size because you're using specific left and top values.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html